# Running an .exe after another closes using .bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm playing an old game that conflicts with the Windows Graphical Shell for Windows 7 and doesn't allow it to display properly so I simply go into Task Manager (TM) and close explorer.exe and the game displays fine but in order for me to enable explorer.exe I need to go into TM and start a new task for it to come back. I was wonder if there was a way to write a .Bat file that would kill explorer.exe launch my game and once the game closes it would simply run the task for me instead of manually needing to turn it back on.

taskkill /f /IM explorer.exe
start CNC95Launcher.exe

this is what i have so far

Answer (score 0):

The `start` causes windows to launch your program asynchronously - that is, it will start it, then continue with the next instruction without waiting for your app to close.

Try this:

```
taskkill /f /IM explorer.exe
start /wait CNC95Launcher.exe
start explorer.exe
```

You probably don't actually need the `start` for explorer, because it's that kind program.

Comment: all that does it launches the explorer after the cnc95 launches the game i need the explorer to remain off untill the game closes

Comment: Sorry, see my edit with `start /wait` this works with windows notepad app to wait until notepad exits.

Comment: i tested the edit and honestly it still does the same thing

Answer (score 0):

I use this (on window 7):

```
taskkill /F /IM Explorer.exe  
*.exe  
Start explorer.exe
```

replace * with the exe name that launches the actual game not a pre launch menu and save as .bat in the same folder directory.

It works for Star Wars Galactic Battlegrounds and AoE which can suffer weird colour issues if explorer runs.